# MVC3 IOC for beginners with Ninject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm trying to get my first internship, and one of the skills required is ASP.Net. They said I needed to bring some code in, so I went though Microsoft's MVC3 tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3)

I changed it around the app around a bit to suit their specifications, which they were fine with.

Now they've asked me to design an interface which will provide IOC. I'm completely new to the topic, and am wondering if anyone knows some good beginner's guides or tips on IOC with MVC. I'm probably going to use ninject.

If you're familiar with the 'movie list' app from the tutorial, they would like me to design an interface which will ensure that the MoviesController will have no awareness of the database.

I know that's pretty vague, but that's pretty much all the instructions they gave me. Anyone have some advice for a IOC newb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it useful to read Scott Allen's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) on abstracting away the dbContext to an interface, then read the MVC3 section of the [ninject wiki](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html) to get your dependency resolution set up.

The basic idea is that you pass your controllers an object implementing a custom interface to the dbContext when you construct them, and thereafter you do all your data manipulation through that object/interface.

That way when you want to test your controllers, you can pass a dummy object that returns whatever data you need without having to create a database full of test data.